# Issues trying to verify JWT in Java using Auth0

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, auth0, verification

I have a website and a Java server that communicate. When a user on the website logs in with proper credentials, the server generates a JWT and sends it to the client. The token is created like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

JwtToken token = new JwtToken(JWT.create()
            .withIssuer(user.getEmail())
            .withClaim("username", user.getUsername())
            .withIssuedAt(cal.getTime())
            .withExpiresAt(addHours(2))
            .sign(algorithm));
```

Where the addHours() method just simply takes the current time and adds n hours to it.

and the algorithm that's used in the sign() is:

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
```

With the secret being generated by:

```
Random random = new Random();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[32];
random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(randomBytes);
```

Which, I think, should create 256 random bits and base64-encode them. (I read somewhere that a secret should be 256 base64-encoded bits, I am unsure if this is correct, please do let me know)

This all works fine, and gives me a token that I think is correct (the https://jwt.io website says it is valid too). Example of a token:  eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJqdXN0aW4yNTA4OTlAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NDQ4MjUzOTIsImlhdCI6MTU0NDgxODE5MiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJKdXN0aW4ifQ.C2Tft5oy8fleYNz4oVCw6S28VGU7YzguA428sZ59QUM

So that token gets send back to the user, and it gets stored as a cookie. When the user tries to access something that requires authentication, they send a request with the token in the 'Authorization' header.

On the server-size I receive that token from the header and try to validate it. This is where I am running into issues. I am current doing the following:

```
DecodedJWT decoded = JWT.decode(token);

JWTVerifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(decoded.getIssuer()).build();

verifier.verify(token);
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256
```

Any help would be much appreciated